# Is this a constructor or a method

Tags: python

Is `__init__` in python a constructor or a method?

Somewhere it says constructor and somewhere it says method, which is quite confusing.

Comment: In [5.3.1. Initializing and Coding Classes](http://www.diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/defining_classes.html#d0e11720) of _Dive Into Python_ it says "It would be tempting but incorrect to call this the constructor" and explains why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is correct to call it a *method*.  It is incorrect, or at best inaccurate, to call it a *constructor*.

Specifically, it is a [magic method](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html).  They are also called special methods, "dunders", and a few other names.

This particular method is used to define the initialisation behavior of an object.  It is not really similar to a constructor, and it is not even the first method to be called on a new instance.

We use `__init__` to set up the state of an already-created instance.  It will be automatically called when we use the syntax `A()` to create an instance of a class `A`, which is why someone might loosely refer to it as a "constructor".  But the responsibility of `__init__` is not related to instance construction, really the `__new__` magic method is more similar to a constructor in that respect.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer by @wim it is worth noting that the object has already been created by the time `__init__` is called i.e. `__init__` is not a constructor. Furthermore, `__init__` methods are *optional*: you do not have to define one.  Finally, an `__init__` method is defined first only by convention i.e. it could be defined after any of the other methods.